# Default javafx tableview scroll bar position

Tags: scrollbar, tableview, javafx-8

I am having tableview at my .fxml file like below,

```
<TableView fx:id="tblViewer" prefHeight="340.0"  prefWidth="800.0" 
                             styleClass="tableview" stylesheets="@ClsMain.css" />
```

I have select box of tables. When I am selecting any table all the data with columns populated into tableview. If columns are more, than tableview automatically render the horizontal scroll bar to it same for vertical scroll bar.

Problem is when I scroll to right end and if I am changing the dropdown selection it is not let me go to the left side. And some of the columns are truncated from the left. Like showing in the image.

[image]

If you have the solution then help me out please.

Kind Regards.

Updated:

Here I am binding the tableview and the data

```
private void initClsTable() {       
        System.out.println("in inintClsTable");
        Bindings.bindContentBidirectional(tblViewer.getColumns(), getViewModel().getColumnList());
        Bindings.bindContentBidirectional(tblViewer.getItems(), getViewModel().getDataList());
    }
```

Here my selection taken place: (When user changes the selection)

```
private void subscribechoosenTableDataConfig() {
        this.columnsList.clear();
        this.dataList.clear();
        System.out.println("subscribechoosenTableDataConfig");      
        if (choosenTableDataConfig.get() != null && choosenTableDataConfig.getValue().getTableName() != null
                && choosenTableDataConfig.getValue().getTableNumber() != 0) {
            clsManager.tell(new ClsManager.ClsTableDataRequest(eventHandler, choosenTableDataConfig.getValue()
                    .getTableName(), choosenTableDataConfig.getValue().getTableNumber()), ActorRef.noSender());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you add more information about the `select box` to your question?

Comment: Question updated please check

Comment: This is *most probably* because you are removing and adding columns dynamically. Can you please add a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to duplicate the issue?

Comment: Great dude, I remove those two lines and it is working fine. How can I thanq dude. Really great solution. Bravo

Comment: I am not sure weather I can provide MCVE due to so many complexity involved in that, but I will try whenever I get free time.

Answer (score 0):

By removing these two lines I have what I wanted.

```
this.columnsList.clear();
this.dataList.clear();
```

Many thanks to  ItachiUchiha